# How to check whether a Linux process has a specific supplementary group without access to /proc/[pid] (hidepid=2)?

Tags: c, linux

`getgroups` syscall allows to get a list of supplementary groups for a current process, but there seems to be no way to do the same for another process.

Is it possible to check by PID (or maybe indirectly) whether another process has a specific supplementary group?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no, and indeed this is roughly the whole purpose of `hidepid=2`: to prevent discovery of identity/ownership of processes belonging to other users. If there were a way, it would probably be considered a security bug unless it were via some mandated standard interface.